# Free work place options in London

Tags: london, work

When travelling I normally hang out in cafes and pubs when working. Now lately I have had some problems with my neck so the laptop style of working is not ideal anymore. On a trip I have a laptop stand like this one.

[image: laptop stand]

With this I get a better ergonomical work situation. I am not particularly keen on assembling one of these in a cafe or a pub and bringing external keyboard and mouse to go with it. In Stockholm there are quite a number of public libraries where it is possible to sit down and do a couple of hours (of coding obviously). What are my options in London for this?

Comment: Have you googled coworking spaces ?

Comment: London has lots of libraries (despite closures)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [**British Library**](http://www.bl.uk/) is a popular choice. Huge, centrally located, free Wifi, spacious, also with lots to see (make sure you look at the [Lindisfarne Gospels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindisfarne_Gospels) while you're there), cafes, and a nice outdoor area if it's sunny.

However, it gets very busy, and competition for a well-placed seat with access to a plug socket can be a bit fierce (by fierce, I mean British fierce, someone might raise an eyebrow and tut), and there's [a bit of registration process](http://www.bl.uk/aboutus/stpancras/wifi/).

---

**Public libraries** are still relatively common outside Central London, despite recent government cuts forcing some to close. Some are run by the council, some by public-private partnerships, so policies vary. Wifi is pretty common - but not necessarily free, especially for non-members. There may be limited desk space, too.

Here's a few lists - but the best bet is probably browse locally with something like Google Maps. With libraries so fragmented I'm not aware of any one site that lists them (you'll find more and better lists of libraries in London, Ontario  than London, England):

- [City of London](http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/services/libraries-and-archives/our-libraries/Pages/default.aspx) have libraries in the East-Central bank district known as "The City"
- [Better](http://www.better.org.uk/libraries) are a social enterprise who run quite a few libraries
- [London Libraries Consortium](https://arena.yourlondonlibrary.net/web/home) also run many libraries
- [British Library have a list](http://www.bl.uk/reshelp/inrrooms/stp/readerbulletin/libguide/publibraries/public.html) of assorted London libraries

---

A good non-obvious option is [**St Pancras Station**](http://stpancras.com/station). It's spacious, much less hellishly busy and noisy than other London stations, and the whole area has excellent free wifi. You can either find a bench or floor space, or (maybe better considering your back condition) make camp in any of the many cafes in the area. As a public space, you can go very early and/or stay very late (just remember that as a public space thousands of people go through, you should be extra-vigilant against opportunistic theft).

---

If you don't mind paying, London has lots of initiatives for **co-working spaces**, many of which charge per day (some are more long-term arrangements). Some are free, but these almost always have some kind of application criteria and long-term commitment required (for example, [Camden Collective](http://camdencollective.co.uk)).

I won't list them because they're constantly opening, closing, going bust, relocating, changing name, changing policies... But [CoWorkingLondon.com](http://www.coworkinglondon.com/) tries to keep track of them all.

---

There's also a site, **http://worksly.com/** that lets you find Wifi "Workspaces" (usually pubs and cafes) near any UK post code.